# Comparativo entre IDEs para java

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide

No próximo semestre terei que escolher entre duas IDEs: NetBeans e Eclipse.

Precisarei desenvolver aplicativos para desktop, e estou com dúvidas em relação a:

- Ferramentas para interface gráfica
- [Requisitos de Hardware](http://www.lge.com/br/computadores/lg-A410-K.BE47P1-5300) para um desempenho considerável
- Compatibilidade com SGBD (PostgresSQL)

Levando em consideração a configuração do meu notebook, o fato do uso ser para estudo (Faculdade),levando em consideração o programa padrão, sem plugins e extensões, o que preciso saber sobre um ou outro?

Comment: Essa pergunta é baseada em **religiões**. Várias perguntas boas geram algum grau de opinião baseadas na **religião** de **evangelistas**...

Comment: se tiver um computador mediano use eclipse, pois é mais leve porem se tiver um pc melhor use netbeans pois tem mais funcionalidades e você acaba sendo mais produtivo.

Comment: Eu acho que algumas edições e indicações de terceiros estão piorando a pergunta. Eu tenho minhas dúvidas se dá para salvá-la a não ser que mude radicalmente e foque em uma ponto específico. Enquanto ficar pedindo uma comparação geral sem critério não vai pra frente. Ele abriu discussão no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2336/101

Comment: Baixe os dois. Ambos suportam Maven.Você pode usar o melhor de cada IDE (e.g., editor de UI do Netbeans e suporte a OSGI do Eclipse). Ninguém vai conseguir te dizer qual o melhor IDE para o seu caso além de você  (todos fazem o básico - code completion, refactoring, navegação, depuração, etc - muito bem). Leveza, responsividade e organização de funcionalidades é questão de gosto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As diferenças entre o **Netbeans** e o **eclipse** são muito poucas, por isso este assunto rapidamente se transforma baseado em opiniões, contudo ficam aqui algumas especificações:

Link:http://development-software.findthebest-sw.com/saved_compare/Eclipse-vs-NetBeans

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Sistema Operativo suportado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Características:**

**Funcionalidades:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Recursos do editor:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Ferramentas de teste:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Plugins disponível:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Controle de Versão:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Bases de dados suportadas:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Total de download:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mínimo de memória:**
[image: img]

<sup>*Como podes reparar as duas IDE's são muito parecidas, logo não optes por nenhuma e usa as duas, ambas servem para programar Java logo ambas vão servir para ti, ainda por cima vais usar a nível educacional, logo o que necessitas, é de ter alguma experiência não um "expert" da IDE, assim no futuro SE na empresa onde trabalhares usar uma ou outra estarás mais a vontade e ai sim passas a um expert da IDE com que a empresa trabalha.*</sup>

Comment: O Eclipse também suporta outros controles de versão além do Git, mas para isso depende de plugins. E também suporta PostgreSQL (tem um driver JDBC para ele), mas do jeito que está escrito dá a impressão que somente o Netbeans é que suporta, o que não é verdade.

Comment: @Piovezan como pode reparar eu fui buscar a informação ao link que postei, nao é da minha autoria, contudo quanto ao "PostgreSQL" não tenho conhecimento mas acredito perfeitamente que funcione, agora quanto ao controle de versão está correto, como mesmo disseste " suporta outros controles de versão além do Git, mas para isso depende de plugins"

Comment: Mas isso respondeu minha pergunta, pois não quero estar instalando plugins...

Comment: Ambos os IDEs são modulares. Isso é verdade para a Plataforma do NetBeans (com sistema de módulos próprios, caminhando em direção ao Apache Felix) e para a Plataforma Eclipse (em cima no Equinox). Por definição ambos os IDES são compostos de uma coleção de *plug-ins*. A principal diferença aqui é só o download inicial. A distribuição com tudo o que tem direito do Netbeans possui suporte a várias coisas que a distribuição padrão Java EE do Eclipse não contempla (e vice-versa); por outro lado não é difícil encontrar distribuições "all inclusive" do Eclipse como o MyEclipse.